# Using Gestures in Metro Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, gestures

I have a MediaElement on my main page and I want to add gestures support in my app. More exactly I want to play/pause the movie when the MediaElement is tapped, increase/decrease the volume when the is a slide up/slide down, or jump to another position in the movie if there is a slide right/slide left. How exactly can i do that ?

My app is designed for Windows Store, so I want the simplest method that I can use for a Metro app. Also I have to say that my application is written in C# and I used XAML for the page design.

Comment: Ah, great question. Looking forward to an answer, too.

Comment: yeah, I'm also still waiting :)